# Crypto service provider in Android

Tags: android, x509certificate, rsacryptoserviceprovider

I need to install more certificates in a tablet PC that run android 4.0.3 and its used by differents users.
Every user need to access to a web that ask certificate for authentication.
I want to protect the private key of every certificate, like in windows with a CSP or some other else, in a way that every user need to put a PIN or password to access the privatre key of proper certificate.
Is possible to do and if yes how.
Thankyou
Piercarlo

Comment: [what have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)